# How to share images in podman?

Tags: podman

I'm trying to use podman to replace docker.  But, I found a problem of share common images.  If on same machine both account john and mary want to use the centos image.  I found both of them must pull one copy in their home directory.  How to share the common images in podman?  By this way, it waste disk space.  Or, I should back to use Docker in this situation?

Comment: It seems, you run podman in a rootless mode. Therefore, it keeps the images in the personal folder. Just my two cents: Amend the storage.conf to point at a shared folder.